# How to merge objects by key in javascript with Lodash

Tags: javascript, object, merge, lodash

I have this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    id: 1, oid: 5, 
    dates: { 
      5: {start_date: "12.30", end_date: "12.31" },
      14: {start_date: "01.01", end_date: "01.15" }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2, oid: 5, 
    dates: { 
      17: {start_date: "02.01", end_date: "02.20" },
      19: {start_date: "03.01", end_date: "03.10" }
    }
  }
]
```

How to merge by "dates" key and get this result with Lodash

```
{
  5: {start_date: "12.30", end_date: "12.31" },
  14: {start_date: "01.01", end_date: "01.15" },
  17: {start_date: "02.01", end_date: "02.20" },
  19: {start_date: "03.01", end_date: "03.10" }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, your expected output is incorrect format

Comment: What is the key ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I gues OP is looking for `[{}, {}, {}]` format.

Comment: @Rajesh, yes, but he grouped by a key. but...what is the name of the key ?\

Comment: OK. I made a mistake by writing the question. I edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Lodash**

You can use [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to get an array of the date objects. To merge the objects to a single one, will use [`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge). We'll use [`_.partial()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial) to add a target object, so we won't mutate the original data. In addition, We'll use the [`_.spread()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#spread) method on the `_.merge()`, so it can handle an array of objects:

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"oid":5,"dates":{"5":{"start_date":"12.30","end_date":"12.31"},"14":{"start_date":"01.01","end_date":"01.15"}}},{"id":2,"oid":5,"dates":{"17":{"start_date":"02.01","end_date":"02.20"},"19":{"start_date":"03.01","end_date":"03.10"}}}];


var result = _.spread(_.partial(_.merge, {}))(_.map(data, 'dates'));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Using ES6**

Pluck the `dates` by using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and flatten by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) into [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"oid":5,"dates":{"5":{"start_date":"12.30","end_date":"12.31"},"14":{"start_date":"01.01","end_date":"01.15"}}},{"id":2,"oid":5,"dates":{"17":{"start_date":"02.01","end_date":"02.20"},"19":{"start_date":"03.01","end_date":"03.10"}}}];

var result = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(data).map((key) => data[key].dates));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but dates is `dates:{}` not `dates:[]`. Maybe i need convert to array?

Comment: Your dates object is invalid, because it lacks property names. This is invalid `{{}}`. This is valid `{ prop: {} }`.

Comment: OK. I made a mistake by writing the question. I edit question.

Answer (score 2):

```
 const output = input.reduce((res, {dates}) => res.concat(dates), []);
```

You may use `reduce` to iterate over the objects and `concat` the results together. Theres no need to use loadash at all.

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you could first [**map**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) the dates and [**assign**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) them together using the [**spread operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
let result = _.assign({}, ..._.map(data, 'dates'))
```